# Excel VBA: Using cell value in SQL where statement

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use 2 cell values as dates in an SQL date range.
I tried the following but it does not work ...

```
Sql = Sql & "WHERE trunc(dh.actshpdate) between " & Worksheets("Source Data").Range("K2").Value & " and " & Worksheets("Source Data").Range("K3").Value & " "
```

... can anyone advise how to amend this code?

Thanks, SMORF

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out ...

```
Sql = Sql & "WHERE trunc(dh.actshpdate) between '" & Worksheets("Source Data").Range("K2").Value & "' and '" & Worksheets("Source Data").Range("K3").Value & "' "
```

Comment: You should find some info about query parameters for the components you're using. It's not safe to concatenate sql with user input (sql injection).